# Factory restore?

Tags: keyboard-layout, setup

I just got a brand new Asus X201E with Ubuntu pre-installed. As I was doing the initial set-up, I was picking out the keyboard layout, trying to figure out which one of the Spanish keyboard layouts was the one I'm used to. All of a sudden it brought up an error message and didn't let me create an account or finish any steps beyond that. Instead it shuffled me along to the main login screen where I had to login with a guest account. What do I need to do to finish the initial set-up steps? Is there a way to just do a factory restore?

Comment: Might be worth sending it back as it is new.

Comment: I don't want to wait a week to be able to use something other than a guest account. I just want to get through the set-up. I'll just install Windows over this if people can't help.

Comment: the computer seems to be working fine, apart from the fact that I have to use a guest login. is there really not a way to do a factory reset?

Comment: I would have thought that they would either supply an installation cd/dvd or have a partition on the hard drive to restore from. Normally I would suggest  downloading the iso and do a fresh install but their image probably includes any relevant drivers for their hardware.

Comment: That's a great idea. Where would I find this partition? I can't quite figure out how to access the hard drive.

Comment: If there is a separate partition it will be listed as a device in nautilus. Check under devices shown in the home folder.

Comment: Thanks. It says I can't access the devices without the account it didn't let me create. I'm going to go to the manufacturer's support site and post an update later

Answer (score 1):

I also have this laptop model. Press F9 on boot to boot from the system recovery partition. You should then be able to reinstall Ubuntu.

Comment: F9 is the standard way. I can confirm that it worked on mine (though I cancelled it). If you show the grub menu during boot, a factory restore option also shows up there.